# Expo React Native app crashing after manually migrationg to Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, expo

I have all my code from JS to Typescript, after finally doing it and trying to run my code it exits with the following error:

```
    ERROR  FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

If i switch to my JS branch and have the old code in the same folders it works like a charm. I don't know where to start looking.

This is how my app structure looks.

[image]